# reimporting a single function in python

Tags: python, function, import

Using python in an interactive mode one imports a module then if the module is changed (a bug fix or something) one can simply use the reload() command.

But what if I didn't import the entire module and used the 'from M import f,g' import statement. Is there any way to reimport only g?

(I tried removing the function from the parameter table by 'del g' AND delete the .pyc file from the directory. It didn't help. when I reimported the function 'from M import g' the old g was loaded).

Comment: simply restart the interpreter ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do a `from foo import bar`, you *are* importing the entire module. You are just making a copy of the symbol `bar` in the current namespace. You are *not* importing just the function.

The `reload` function is not totally reliable (e.g. it will not work for compiled C modules). I would recommend that you exit and restart your interpreter.

Comment: +1 for making it clear on importing module vs incorporating symbol in namespace.

Comment: This doesn't work in a simple way on python 2.7.3 - when I `from foo import bar`, the symbol `foo` doesn't get defined. The module does have an entry in `sys.modules`, so I can successfully `reload(sys.modules['foo'])` (after `import sys` of course).

Answer (score 5):

For `from M import f, g` where `M` is not an official python module, use:

```
import sys
import importlib
importlib.reload(sys.modules['M'])
```

then, reimport `f` and `g` using:

```
from M import f,g
```

If `M` is an official python module, use

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(M)
from M import f,g
```

Comment: This is the right way in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is just for the interactive interpreter, I don't think that something like:

```
def my_reload(mod, name):
    reload(mod)
    globals()[name] = getattr(mod, name)

myreload(somemodule, "some_function")
```

would be terrible. This just reloads the module like normal and then rebinds the name pointing at the old object to the new object. This should work in all instances in which `reload` would work to begin with. Alternatively, you could program it to take the actual object and get the name using its `__name__` attribute. Functions, classes and modules all have a `__name__` attribute but something like a module-level dictionary doesn't so it wouldn't be as flexible.

It will not replace references to the object that exist other than the global one but neither would `reload` even if you originally accessed it with the dotted name. Once a reference to an object is loose, there's not much that you can do.

Answer (score 0):

For the first import, bind the imported piece to a variable (which also speeds up look-up):

```
import numpy as NP
import numpy.linalg as LA
  ...
reload(LA)
```